# 406 HTTP error caused by URL on text input

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form, `method='post'` with `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and a text input inside where users insert a YouTube video [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator).

When the URL looks like `http://...` or `https://...`, after submitting form, I receive error 406. But when it looks like `www.youtube...`, everything goes OK. I tried `<input type="url"`, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<input type="text"
```

If you need to remove the actual `http://` part before submitting the form you'll want to use a regex pattern to remove it ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206269/javascript-how-to-remove-http-from-url)).

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
<input type = "text" id = "mytextbox" onkeyup = "striphttp()">
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function striphttp() {
            var url = document.getElementById("mytextbox").value;
            url = url.replace(/http:\/\/w/gi,"w");
            document.getElementById("mytextbox").value = url;
        }
    </script>
```